# Error Message: Storage is Corrupt

Tags: commcare

One of our partners has reported an increase in users who are seeing the following error (since around November 2016). FLWs are using devices with Android version 4.4. Thoughts on why this could be happening?

[image: error message]

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

This could occur for a few reasons:

1. The applications storage files have been changed - Some of CommCare's files non-userdata files are stored on the phone in an area where external apps can delete them. This used to be a rampant problem on Android phones which used the SD card to store certain files.
2. The phones storage layer has corrupted the files on the device - this tends to be a problem with counterfeit SD cards or off-brand devices.
3. If in an area with poor connectivity, the application may not have been fully downloaded.

Reinstalling the application might resolve the issue. I would also not rule out the possibility of a bug, so would report an issue with their support team if that doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: More docs here as well: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Recovery+Mode